# Правильно написано?

Tags: синтаксис

В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого, я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь возможны или двоеточие, или тире, но тире предпочтительнее, так как вторая часть сложного предложения противопоставлена первой части. Для двоеточия в этом предложении есть элемент причины во второй части, но он слаб (В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого (почему?), потому что я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством. - По смыслу не очень убедительные причинно-следственные отношения)

Answer (score 0):

Задача имеет авторское решение:

(1)В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого, я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством (обусловленность двух сообщений не обозначена).

(2)В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого: я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством (обозначены следственно-причинные отношения: так как всего приходится добиваться).

(3)В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого - я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством (это вариант 2 в форме присоединительной конструкции).

Comment: Вариант 2 странноват: Ничего легкого не бывает, потому что я всё время напрягаюсь, то есть сама виновата. А можно ли вариант 3 рассматривать как причинно-следственный: Ничего легкого не бывает, поэтому я стараюсь?

Comment: Тат, а у вас свой вариант есть? В принципе я с вами согласен насчет второго варианта. Я бы предложил бы парцелляцию.В моей жизни ничего не бывает легкого. Я добиваюсь всего старанием,трудом и упорством. Что скажите? Чтобы избежать ненужных оттенков.

Comment: Смысл такой: жизнь не преподнесла мне подарков (богатых родителей, блестящих способностей) - успехов мне приходится добиваться старанием, трудом и упорством - поэтому в моей жизни нет ничего легкого. Мне кажется, здесь изложены объективные причины, фактические наблюдения автора, а не его убеждения в том, что успех приходит к тому, кто трудится. Думаю, что это отношения  "следствие - причина", или,  вернее, "вывод - факт".

Comment: Ваши предположения вполне обоснованы. Но все , на мой взгляд, остается двусмысленность. То, о чем писал Тат. Хотя, мне кажется, такие нюансы не каждый сможет уловить.

Comment: Я бы выбрала тире. Двоеточие категорически не нравится, потому что всех домысленных слов типа "мне ПРИХОДИТСЯ добиваться", "жизнь ВЫНУЖДАЕТ добиваться" и пр. там нет, а есть "жизнь нелегкая, потому что я добиваюсь старанием". А если не стараться, то, может, и полегчает.

Comment: Чтобы ничего не домысливать, лучше остановиться на первом варианте.

Answer (score -2):

Вас интересует синтаксис данного преждложения?

Во-первых, я бы исправил слово *ничего* на *ничто*. Во-вторых, это, несомненно, бессоюзное сложное предложение. В нём две предикативные (грамматические) основы: [ничего не бывает] и [я добиваюсь]. Вторая часть этого предложения  осложнена однородными членами предложения (однородными обстоятельствами). Длбиваюсь (чего?) всего (как?) трудом...

По существу, предложение вполне корректно.

Comment: Не бывает (чего?) ничего легкого. А Вы предлагаете: не бывает (чего?) ничто легкого Это по-русски: ничто легкого...

Comment: Что? Меня этому один форумачанин научил (tat - её никнейм). 

Не бывает (что?) ничто.

Comment: Ой, я в домике! Задаем вопрос: не бывает чего? - ничего; не дается что? - ничто (Ничто не дается легко). Обычно ошибку допускают во фразах типа "Его ничего не интересует" (не интересует что? ничто), "Ничего не болит" (не болит что? ничто) и т.д.

Comment: "Его ничего не интересует" - не ошибка, просто разговорное, а "ничего не болит" и вовсе литературное.

Comment: Так разговорное по отношению к письменной речи и есть ошибка - любой корректор исправит, если фраза не в диалоге и не характеризует персонажа. Кстати, разговорное - часть литературного. Противопоставляется не разг. и литер., а устное и письменное. Оба выражения разговорные. "Ничто" здесь существительное, а не отрицательное местоимение, стоит в форме именительного падежа и выполняет функцию подлежащего.